# Create a tutorial site similar to Google Codelabs

Tags: google-code

I'm trying to develop a tutorial site similar to [Google CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/).

I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools) article for develop a CodeLabs site.

Has anyone tried to used this tool for hosting their own CodeLabs site?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. I looked around and found this. https://github.com/googlecodelabs/codelab-components. It appears the site is using Polymer. https://www.polymer-project.org/

Comment: So this is just survey kind of question? *Yes* or *No*? What is specifically intended ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the source code to create CodeLabs in your own machine.

You will need Go Lang for this or you can use the provided installers in the release section of Github.

Refer to https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/blob/master/claat/README.md